# Querying With SQL From Two Tables

Tags: sql

I am working on changing a query. I have this sample:

```
SELECT  
      ItemID,
      Item                        
FROM Transactions tbm                          
WHERE TransactionType IN ('Receipt','Issue')   
GROUP BY ItemID ,Item
```

What I want to do is change the **transactions** table. Now, I have **Receipt** and **Issue** table and I want to get *QuatityReceipt* from **Receipt** table and *QuantityIssued* from **Issue** table. *ItemID* and *Item* are common on both.

How can I do this with one query?
Thanks.

Comment: Not clear what you want ? Put some sample data and expected output in question.

Comment: You need to `JOIN` your tables. Try googling a bit, you should get what you are looking for...

Comment: GROUP BY without any aggregate functions (e.g. SUM, COUNT, MAX), doesn't make much sense. Perhaps you want SELECT DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

As said before you need to join your tables like this:

```
SELECT 
      T.ItemID,
      T.Item,
      R.QuatityReceipt,
      I.QuantityIssued
 FROM Transactions AS T
JOIN Receipt AS R ON T.ItemID=R.ItemID
JOIN Issue AS I ON T.ItemID=I.ItemID
```

Comment: I dont have Transactions Table anymore :(

Comment: So can you give us the description of the tables you want to Querying ?